# How to read stackoverflow archive post data to python?

Tags: python, xml, csv

I downloaded the archival data of stackoverflow posts from https://archive.org/details/stackexchange.

However, after expanding the 7z file, I have a 103GB xml file of posts.

I tried to use python to load it but the server failed.

What can I do to load such a large file to python to analyze the data?

I tried the codes from following links: [how to convert xml file to csv using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772537/how-to-convert-xml-file-to-csv-using-python-script)

[XML to CSV Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898661/xml-to-csv-python)

But python stopped at the step of open the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is challenging i also suffered the same issue,

Instead of loading files completely in the RAM. you can stream the file. For XML file streaming you can use python's `ElementTree.`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def process_element(elem):
    # your code goes here
    print(elem.tag, elem.attrib)

file_path = 'demo.xml'

# Create a parser
context = ET.iterparse(file_path, events=('start', 'end'))

# Iterate the file
for event, elem in context:
    if event == 'end':  
        process_element(elem)
        elem.clear()  # Free up memory

# Must not forget
context.root.clear()
```

Comment: Thank you! I used fileinput library to work on it line by line in the end